# What is the practical difference between using an FTDI breakout board and an FTDI cable?

Tags: arduino, ftdi

I have some 3.3V Arduino Pro Mini boards and they require either an FTDI cable or breakout board to be programmed from a USB port.
So far I've been using a board, but it's annoying to have to either solder headers in place or hold the boards carefully every time I make a modification to the code. Also, switching between 3.3V boards and 5V requires resoldering traces on the FTDI board.

The process goes like this:
- ensure FTDI board is soldered for the correct voltage, resolder if necessary.
- connect FTDI board to arduino pro mini.
- plug mini usb cable into FTDI board.
- carefully hold arduino and FTDI board in place.
- click upload in the Arduino IDE.

Then everything works.

I am aware that FTDI cables don't always support 'auto-reset', but I've never had to manually reset my Arduino in order to load new code.
When does one have to press the reset button if using a cable?
before uploading?
afterwards?
What's the deal here?

Also, can I use a USB FTDI cable to load 3.3V and 5V boards?

Comment: The board has the circuit on the board with a generic cable and FTDI cables have the circuit board built into the cable on a connector.

Comment: @kenny: Thanks for taking the time to reply, but your comment doesn't answer the question which is what is the _practical_ difference?  
Namely, how or when do I have to reset the board when using a cable, and which board voltages does a cable support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I keep one FTDI cable around that I've terminated with breadboard pins for quickly connecting to, well, a breadboard! so I don't have a cable always hanging off my prototypes.  I haven't bothered to implement auto-reset; I just use a reset button on the board.  The timing that almost always works for me (in Eclipse) is to hold the reset button and release it just as I click Eclipse's download button.  (Maybe someday I'll make a tiny PC boards to arrange all four pins into a pseudo BB-plug....)

This cable came with NerdKit AVR kit that was 5v based.  So are my BB designs, currently.  The FTDI head is on the USB-A male end; I just measured the BB end at 5.09v with no load (except, obviously, the meter).  I think you only need to provide the appropriate regulator - 3.3v or 5v - as long as the input to it is higher than that (within reason).  I power BB's with a 9v battery when I'm not using the cable.

Comment: So am I to understand that I could plug a 3.3V Arduino pro mini into a 5V FTDI board without frying it? (in which case what's the point of the 3.3V board?) Is the V+ of the FTDI not wired directly to the Vin of the board? I didn't think it goes through the regulator. Obviously I'm reluctant to test this for fear of frying the board.

Comment: No, you wouldn't want to put 5V on the Vcc rail of a 3.3V Arduino; only put that on its RAW input.  The Arduino site has this description of the [ProMini](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardProMini) - see "Power" halfway down the page. Consider your FTDI's 5V output to be unregulated as far as a 3.3V chip is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a cable without auto-reset (or a older board) you need to hit the reset button before uploading the new sketch.

It will depend on the cable what voltage they support, sparkfun for instance has [some](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9717) that claims can do both. And this is from sparkfun's page

> These have 5V VCC, and 3.3V I/O. The 5V Vcc output shouldn't be a problem unless this cable is being used to power a sensitive circuit such as a sensor.
>
> There are pros and cons to the FTDI Cable vs the FTDI Basic. The FTDI Basic has great LED indicators, but requires a Mini-B cable. The FTDI Cable is well protected against the elements, but is large and cannot be embedded into a project as easily. The FTDI Basic uses DTR to cause a hardware reset where the FTDI cable uses the RTS signal.

Comment: So am I to understand that I could plug a 3.3V Arduino pro mini into a 5V FTDI board without frying it? (in which case what's the point of the 3.3V board?) Is the V+ of the FTDI not wired directly to the Vin of the board? I didn't think it goes through the regulator. Obviously I'm reluctant to test this for fear of frying the board.

Comment: No, don't do it;) That cable in the link works with both, but not all does.